# Chrome developer tools WebSQL, can't see the data in massive SQL query

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, web-sql

I have a set of massive SQL queries, they have so many columns that I cannot see any data returned from WebSQL in Chrome developer tools (screenshot below), one way to go about this would be obviously to break the queries apart into smaller ones however I am looking into quite a few, and breaking down gives me huge overhead. Other way would be to run the queries in JS and observe them in console problem is I not always get single line results and then I find it nearly impossible to figure out what's what.
Is there a way to work around this, like enabling horizontal bar for example, or some other technique (like add-on) that would be not time consuming and would allow to observe the data retuned?

[image]

**UPDATE:** My colleague proposed a semi-joke solution: If multiple monitors are being used  stretch Chrome across multiple monitor windows.

**UPDATE2**

to reproduce issue one can run following query

```
var db = openDatabase('movies', '1.0', 'movies database', 50 * 1024 * 1024);

db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE userinfo4 (id INTEGER, player TEXT, company0 TEXT, company1 TEXT, company2 TEXT, company3 TEXT, company4 TEXT, company5 TEXT, company6 TEXT, company7 TEXT, company8 TEXT, company9 TEXT, company10 TEXT, company11 TEXT, company12 TEXT, company13 TEXT, company14 TEXT, company15 TEXT, company16 TEXT, company17 TEXT, company18 TEXT, company19 TEXT, company20 TEXT, company21 TEXT, company22 TEXT, company23 TEXT, company24 TEXT, company25 TEXT, company26 TEXT, company27 TEXT, company28 TEXT, company29 TEXT, company30 TEXT, company31 TEXT, company32 TEXT, company33 TEXT, company34 TEXT, company35 TEXT, company36 TEXT, company37 TEXT, company38 TEXT, company39 TEXT, company40 TEXT, company41 TEXT, company42 TEXT, company43 TEXT, company44 TEXT, company45 TEXT, company46 TEXT, company47 TEXT, company48 TEXT, company49 TEXT, company50 TEXT, company51 TEXT, company52 TEXT, company53 TEXT, company54 TEXT, company55 TEXT, company56 TEXT, company57 TEXT, company58 TEXT, company59 TEXT, company60 TEXT, company61 TEXT, company62 TEXT, company63 TEXT, company64 TEXT, company65 TEXT, company66 TEXT, company67 TEXT, company68 TEXT, company69 TEXT, company70 TEXT, company71 TEXT, company72 TEXT, company73 TEXT, company74 TEXT, company75 TEXT, company76 TEXT, company77 TEXT, company78 TEXT, company79 TEXT, company80 TEXT, company81 TEXT, company82 TEXT, company83 TEXT, company84 TEXT, company85 TEXT, company86 TEXT, company87 TEXT, company88 TEXT, company89 TEXT, company90 TEXT, company91 TEXT, company92 TEXT, company93 TEXT, company94 TEXT, company95 TEXT, company96 TEXT, company97 TEXT, company98 TEXT, company99 TEXT)');
    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO userinfo4 select 0, 'player0', 'company0','company1','company2','company3','company4','company5','company6','company7','company8','company9','company10','company11','company12','company13','company14','company15','company16','company17','company18','company19','company20','company21','company22','company23','company24','company25','company26','company27','company28','company29','company30','company31','company32','company33','company34','company35','company36','company37','company38','company39','company40','company41','company42','company43','company44','company45','company46','company47','company48','company49','company50','company51','company52','company53','company54','company55','company56','company57','company58','company59','company60','company61','company62','company63','company64','company65','company66','company67','company68','company69','company70','company71','company72','company73','company74','company75','company76','company77','company78','company79','company80','company81','company82','company83','company84','company85','company86','company87','company88','company89','company90','company91','company92','company93','company94','company95','company96','company97','company98','company99' UNION select 1, 'player1', 'company0','company1','company2','company3','company4','company5','company6','company7','company8','company9','company10','company11','company12','company13','company14','company15','company16','company17','company18','company19','company20','company21','company22','company23','company24','company25','company26','company27','company28','company29','company30','company31','company32','company33','company34','company35','company36','company37','company38','company39','company40','company41','company42','company43','company44','company45','company46','company47','company48','company49','company50','company51','company52','company53','company54','company55','company56','company57','company58','company59','company60','company61','company62','company63','company64','company65','company66','company67','company68','company69','company70','company71','company72','company73','company74','company75','company76','company77','company78','company79','company80','company81','company82','company83','company84','company85','company86','company87','company88','company89','company90','company91','company92','company93','company94','company95','company96','company97','company98','company99' UNION select 2, 'player2', 'company0','company1','company2','company3','company4','company5','company6','company7','company8','company9','company10','company11','company12','company13','company14','company15','company16','company17','company18','company19','company20','company21','company22','company23','company24','company25','company26','company27','company28','company29','company30','company31','company32','company33','company34','company35','company36','company37','company38','company39','company40','company41','company42','company43','company44','company45','company46','company47','company48','company49','company50','company51','company52','company53','company54','company55','company56','company57','company58','company59','company60','company61','company62','company63','company64','company65','company66','company67','company68','company69','company70','company71','company72','company73','company74','company75','company76','company77','company78','company79','company80','company81','company82','company83','company84','company85','company86','company87','company88','company89','company90','company91','company92','company93','company94','company95','company96','company97','company98','company99' UNION select 3, 'player3', 'company0','company1','company2','company3','company4','company5','company6','company7','company8','company9','company10','company11','company12','company13','company14','company15','company16','company17','company18','company19','company20','company21','company22','company23','company24','company25','company26','company27','company28','company29','company30','company31','company32','company33','company34','company35','company36','company37','company38','company39','company40','company41','company42','company43','company44','company45','company46','company47','company48','company49','company50','company51','company52','company53','company54','company55','company56','company57','company58','company59','company60','company61','company62','company63','company64','company65','company66','company67','company68','company69','company70','company71','company72','company73','company74','company75','company76','company77','company78','company79','company80','company81','company82','company83','company84','company85','company86','company87','company88','company89','company90','company91','company92','company93','company94','company95','company96','company97','company98','company99' UNION select 4, 'player4', 'company0','company1','company2','company3','company4','company5','company6','company7','company8','company9','company10','company11','company12','company13','company14','company15','company16','company17','company18','company19','company20','company21','company22','company23','company24','company25','company26','company27','company28','company29','company30','company31','company32','company33','company34','company35','company36','company37','company38','company39','company40','company41','company42','company43','company44','company45','company46','company47','company48','company49','company50','company51','company52','company53','company54','company55','company56','company57','company58','company59','company60','company61','company62','company63','company64','company65','company66','company67','company68','company69','company70','company71','company72','company73','company74','company75','company76','company77','company78','company79','company80','company81','company82','company83','company84','company85','company86','company87','company88','company89','company90','company91','company92','company93','company94','company95','company96','company97','company98','company99' UNION select 5, 'player5', 'company0','company1','company2','company3','company4','company5','company6','company7','company8','company9','company10','company11','company12','company13','company14','company15','company16','company17','company18','company19','company20','company21','company22','company23','company24','company25','company26','company27','company28','company29','company30','company31','company32','company33','company34','company35','company36','company37','company38','company39','company40','company41','company42','company43','company44','company45','company46','company47','company48','company49','company50','company51','company52','company53','company54','company55','company56','company57','company58','company59','company60','company61','company62','company63','company64','company65','company66','company67','company68','company69','company70','company71','company72','company73','company74','company75','company76','company77','company78','company79','company80','company81','company82','company83','company84','company85','company86','company87','company88','company89','company90','company91','company92','company93','company94','company95','company96','company97','company98','company99' UNION select 6, 'player6', 'company0','company1','company2','company3','company4','company5','company6','company7','company8','company9','company10','company11','company12','company13','company14','company15','company16','company17','company18','company19','company20','company21','company22','company23','company24','company25','company26','company27','company28','company29','company30','company31','company32','company33','company34','company35','company36','company37','company38','company39','company40','company41','company42','company43','company44','company45','company46','company47','company48','company49','company50','company51','company52','company53','company54','company55','company56','company57','company58','company59','company60','company61','company62','company63','company64','company65','company66','company67','company68','company69','company70','company71','company72','company73','company74','company75','company76','company77','company78','company79','company80','company81','company82','company83','company84','company85','company86','company87','company88','company89','company90','company91','company92','company93','company94','company95','company96','company97','company98','company99' UNION select 7, 'player7', 'company0','company1','company2','company3','company4','company5','company6','company7','company8','company9','company10','company11','company12','company13','company14','company15','company16','company17','company18','company19','company20','company21','company22','company23','company24','company25','company26','company27','company28','company29','company30','company31','company32','company33','company34','company35','company36','company37','company38','company39','company40','company41','company42','company43','company44','company45','company46','company47','company48','company49','company50','company51','company52','company53','company54','company55','company56','company57','company58','company59','company60','company61','company62','company63','company64','company65','company66','company67','company68','company69','company70','company71','company72','company73','company74','company75','company76','company77','company78','company79','company80','company81','company82','company83','company84','company85','company86','company87','company88','company89','company90','company91','company92','company93','company94','company95','company96','company97','company98','company99' UNION select 8, 'player8', 'company0','company1','company2','company3','company4','company5','company6','company7','company8','company9','company10','company11','company12','company13','company14','company15','company16','company17','company18','company19','company20','company21','company22','company23','company24','company25','company26','company27','company28','company29','company30','company31','company32','company33','company34','company35','company36','company37','company38','company39','company40','company41','company42','company43','company44','company45','company46','company47','company48','company49','company50','company51','company52','company53','company54','company55','company56','company57','company58','company59','company60','company61','company62','company63','company64','company65','company66','company67','company68','company69','company70','company71','company72','company73','company74','company75','company76','company77','company78','company79','company80','company81','company82','company83','company84','company85','company86','company87','company88','company89','company90','company91','company92','company93','company94','company95','company96','company97','company98','company99' UNION select 9, 'player9', 'company0','company1','company2','company3','company4','company5','company6','company7','company8','company9','company10','company11','company12','company13','company14','company15','company16','company17','company18','company19','company20','company21','company22','company23','company24','company25','company26','company27','company28','company29','company30','company31','company32','company33','company34','company35','company36','company37','company38','company39','company40','company41','company42','company43','company44','company45','company46','company47','company48','company49','company50','company51','company52','company53','company54','company55','company56','company57','company58','company59','company60','company61','company62','company63','company64','company65','company66','company67','company68','company69','company70','company71','company72','company73','company74','company75','company76','company77','company78','company79','company80','company81','company82','company83','company84','company85','company86','company87','company88','company89','company90','company91','company92','company93','company94','company95','company96','company97','company98','company99' UNION select 10, 'player10', 'company0','company1','company2','company3','company4','company5','company6','company7','company8','company9','company10','company11','company12','company13','company14','company15','company16','company17','company18','company19','company20','company21','company22','company23','company24','company25','company26','company27','company28','company29','company30','company31','company32','company33','company34','company35','company36','company37','company38','company39','company40','company41','company42','company43','company44','company45','company46','company47','company48','company49','company50','company51','company52','company53','company54','company55','company56','company57','company58','company59','company60','company61','company62','company63','company64','company65','company66','company67','company68','company69','company70','company71','company72','company73','company74','company75','company76','company77','company78','company79','company80','company81','company82','company83','company84','company85','company86','company87','company88','company89','company90','company91','company92','company93','company94','company95','company96','company97','company98','company99' UNION select 11, 'player11', 'company0','company1','company2','company3','company4','company5','company6','company7','company8','company9','company10','company11','company12','company13','company14','company15','company16','company17','company18','company19','company20','company21','company22','company23','company24','company25','company26','company27','company28','company29','company30','company31','company32','company33','company34','company35','company36','company37','company38','company39','company40','company41','company42','company43','company44','company45','company46','company47','company48','company49','company50','company51','company52','company53','company54','company55','company56','company57','company58','company59','company60','company61','company62','company63','company64','company65','company66','company67','company68','company69','company70','company71','company72','company73','company74','company75','company76','company77','company78','company79','company80','company81','company82','company83','company84','company85','company86','company87','company88','company89','company90','company91','company92','company93','company94','company95','company96','company97','company98','company99' UNION select 12, 'player12', 'company0','company1','company2','company3','company4','company5','company6','company7','company8','company9','company10','company11','company12','company13','company14','company15','company16','company17','company18','company19','company20','company21','company22','company23','company24','company25','company26','company27','company28','company29','company30','company31','company32','company33','company34','company35','company36','company37','company38','company39','company40','company41','company42','company43','company44','company45','company46','company47','company48','company49','company50','company51','company52','company53','company54','company55','company56','company57','company58','company59','company60','company61','company62','company63','company64','company65','company66','company67','company68','company69','company70','company71','company72','company73','company74','company75','company76','company77','company78','company79','company80','company81','company82','company83','company84','company85','company86','company87','company88','company89','company90','company91','company92','company93','company94','company95','company96','company97','company98','company99' UNION select 13, 'player13', 'company0','company1','company2','company3','company4','company5','company6','company7','company8','company9','company10','company11','company12','company13','company14','company15','company16','company17','company18','company19','company20','company21','company22','company23','company24','company25','company26','company27','company28','company29','company30','company31','company32','company33','company34','company35','company36','company37','company38','company39','company40','company41','company42','company43','company44','company45','company46','company47','company48','company49','company50','company51','company52','company53','company54','company55','company56','company57','company58','company59','company60','company61','company62','company63','company64','company65','company66','company67','company68','company69','company70','company71','company72','company73','company74','company75','company76','company77','company78','company79','company80','company81','company82','company83','company84','company85','company86','company87','company88','company89','company90','company91','company92','company93','company94','company95','company96','company97','company98','company99' UNION select 14, 'player14', 'company0','company1','company2','company3','company4','company5','company6','company7','company8','company9','company10','company11','company12','company13','company14','company15','company16','company17','company18','company19','company20','company21','company22','company23','company24','company25','company26','company27','company28','company29','company30','company31','company32','company33','company34','company35','company36','company37','company38','company39','company40','company41','company42','company43','company44','company45','company46','company47','company48','company49','company50','company51','company52','company53','company54','company55','company56','company57','company58','company59','company60','company61','company62','company63','company64','company65','company66','company67','company68','company69','company70','company71','company72','company73','company74','company75','company76','company77','company78','company79','company80','company81','company82','company83','company84','company85','company86','company87','company88','company89','company90','company91','company92','company93','company94','company95','company96','company97','company98','company99'");
});
```

Comment: raised on chromium https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=503045 please upvote if you want this fixed.